# SQLAlchemy Engine vs Session

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

In the documentation it says session.close()
"releases any connection resources. connections are returned to the connection pool"

engine.close() will close the connection and the pool will be replenished with new connection object is my understanding right

Comment: There is no such method `Engine.close()`. Did you mean [`Connection.close()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.close)?

Comment: Its Engine.dispose()

Comment: Why don't you read the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.dispose), then? It's quite clear on what dispose does. Not all connections are closed on dispose, but only the ones checked in at the time of dispose, and no replenishment is done, but an entirely new pool is created. The 2 methods, `Session.close()` and `Engine.dispose()` are pretty different.